# How does one reproduce this plot in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, julia, plotly.js

Can we plot over on existing layer in JS? For example, in Julia, this code produces the plot below.

```
using Plots
# create xs and ys using a parametric coordinate system
t = collect(-10.:0.1:10.)
c = collect(-10:10)
x = fill(0., length(t), length(c))
y = similar(x)
f(x) = -exp(x) * x
for (i, val) in enumerate(c)
    a = f.(t) .+ val
    b = t .^ 2 + a .^ 2
    x[:, i] = 2. * t .* a .^2 ./ b
    y[:, i] = 2. * t .^2 .* a ./ b
end

# plot over with plot!
p = plot(x[:, 1], y[:, 1], leg = false, showaxis = false, grid = false, xticks = :none, yticks = :none)
for j = 2:length(c)
        p = plot!(x[:,j], y[:,j], leg = false, grid = false, showaxis = false, xticks = :none, yticks = :none)
end
p
savefig(p)
```

[Cool chart!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnygG.png)

I am struggling to reproduce this in JS. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to plot it using Plotly.js. If there is a more efficient way, would love to see it. Thanks.

```
        const data = createLabels(g);
        console.log(data);

        var layout = {
            showlegend: false,
            autosize: true,
            xaxis: {
                showticklabels: false,
                showline: false,
                zeroline: false,
                showgrid: false
            },
            yaxis: {
                showticklabels: false,
                showline: false,
                zeroline: false,
                showgrid: false
            }
        };

        Plotly.newPlot('div1', data, layout, { scrollZoom: true });

        function createLabels(g) {
            var t = -10;
            var c = -10;
            var dat = [];
            for (c = -10; c < 10; c++) {
                var x = [];
                var y = [];
                for (t = -10; t < 10; t = t + 0.1) {
                    var f = g(t) + c;
                    var u1 = 2 * t * f * f / (t ** 2 + f ** 2);
                    var u2 = 2 * t * t * f / (t ** 2 + f ** 2);
                    x.push(u1);
                    y.push(u2);
                };
                dat.push({ x: x, y: y })
            }
            return dat;
        }

        function g(u) {
            return -Math.exp(u) * u;
        }
```